# Setup grafana with graphite

Tags: 14.04, graphite

I want to make daschbord in grafana using the metris from graphite.
I was following this link http://docs.grafana.org/datasources/graphite/ 
but i didn´t succeed to make a connection between them

[image]

should i make some modification in the configuration, or i have another problem ?
I appreciate your help

Comment: What OS are you using? This looks like Bodhi Linux 3.

Comment: @StarOS  Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Comment: Thanks. This looked like the setup of Bodhi Linux 3.4.1 a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was following this link to configure Apache for graphite-web application and it works :) 
https://github.com/spariev/docs/commit/99582d8681be24dd9379298aa854112e9acaadec

Answer (score 0):

1. Please clear cookie and saved passwords.
2. Are you really can open http://graphite-site:8080 ? Is it open without errors and basic auth ?
3. If 1 and 2 are true - please take a screenshot of graphite site. May it opens as http://somesite:8080/graphite ?

Comment: I cannot open graphite-site:8080....what does it mean ?

Comment: Hm, ok.

Grafana is just a frontend for a your graphite. 
Your should tell to grafana - where're it can find graphite.

So, you should open in browser your graphite, if you will be prompted for a basic auth login and password, you should remember it.

Next , you should tell grafana a url for a graphite, and if you are using basic auth - login and password.

Could you post your web server config for a graphite ?

Comment: Thx for the explanation  ....what is the name of the file of configuration ? is it local_settings.py ?

Comment: webserver's config, that you use for graphite. For example: apache, nginx, uwsgi or any other web server.